# Issues with MVC 4 validation attributes on a production server

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, attributes

I have been working on this issue for several days now and have been unable to find a solution. I will try to be as specific as I can, so that you understand the problem, and include code where necessary.

I have a normal view with a Html.BeginForm (as seen in the first code example) with different controls inside, as well as ValidationMessageFors for some of them. In the model (the second example) we have a couple validation attributes for some of the properties, just like any other MVC setup. The issue is that locally when the page is run, the data-val-required attribute, as well as others, are all added to the html, but when deployed to the production server, these attributes are never added, and so the validation doesn't work. Examples 3 and 4 show this. Example 5 shows the script file declarations.

---

Example 1:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{      
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DocumentID);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TempFilePath);
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FileName); 
<div style="height: 27px; width: 769px; background-color: #b3b3b3; padding-top: 7px; padding-right: 14px; padding-left: 14px; border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;">
    <span style="font-size: 11.5pt; font-weight: bold; float: left;">@ViewBag.Title</span>
</div>
<br />
<div style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <h4>Document Name</h4>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { id = "DocumentNameEdit" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "*", new { @style = "font-size:16pt;" })
    <br />
    <h4>Description</h4>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { id = "DocumentDescriptionEdit" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "*", new { @style = "font-size:16pt;" })
    <br />

    <input type="button" id="btnSaveDocument" value="Save" />
    <input type="button" id="btnClose" value="Close" />
</div>
}
```

Example 2:

```
public class DocumentModel
{
    public DocumentModel()
    {
        Statuses = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem() {Text="Visible", Value="3"},
            new SelectListItem() {Text="Hidden", Value="4"}
        };
    }

    public string DocumentID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Please enter no more than 255 characters for the Name.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Name is Required") ]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(2000, ErrorMessage = "Please enter no more than 2000 characters for the Description.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is Required")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public int? Status { get; set; }
    public string FolderID { get; set; }
    public string TempFilePath { get; set; }
    public List<dm_LIST_Folders_Result> FolderList { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Statuses { get; set; }
}
```

Example 3 (local):

```
<form method="post" action="/DPS/Documents/CreateEdit" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="hidden" value="TheCode" name="__RequestVerificationToken">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="DocumentID" id="DocumentID">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="TempFilePath" id="TempFilePath">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="FileName" id="FileName">    
    <div style="height: 27px; width: 769px; background-color: #b3b3b3; padding-top: 7px; padding-right: 14px; padding-left: 14px; border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;">
        <span style="font-size: 11.5pt; font-weight: bold; float: left;">Add New Document</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;">

        <h4>Document Name</h4>
        <input type="text" value="" name="Name" id="DocumentNameEdit" data-val-required="Name is Required" data-val-length-max="255" data-val-length="Please enter no more than 255 characters for the Name." data-val="true">
        <span style="font-size:16pt;" data-valmsg-replace="false" data-valmsg-for="Name" class="field-validation-valid">*</span>
        <br>
        <h4>Description</h4>
        <textarea rows="2" name="Description" id="DocumentDescriptionEdit" data-val-required="Description is Required" data-val-length-max="2000" data-val-length="Please enter no more than 2000 characters for the Description." data-val="true" cols="20"></textarea>
        <span style="font-size:16pt;" data-valmsg-replace="false" data-valmsg-for="Description" class="field-validation-valid">*</span>
        <br>

        <input type="button" value="Save" id="btnSaveDocument">
        <input type="button" value="Close" id="btnClose">
    </div>
</form>
```

Example 4 (Production)

```
<form method="post" action="/DM/DPS/Documents/CreateEdit" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="hidden" value="TheCode" name="__RequestVerificationToken">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="DocumentID" id="DocumentID">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="TempFilePath" id="TempFilePath">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="FileName" id="FileName">    
    <div style="height: 27px; width: 769px; background-color: #b3b3b3; padding-top: 7px; padding-right: 14px; padding-left: 14px; border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;">
        <span style="font-size: 11.5pt; font-weight: bold; float: left;">Add New Document</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;">

        <h4>Document Name</h4>


<input type="text" value="" name="Name" id="Name">

        <br>
        <h4>Description</h4>
        <textarea rows="2" name="Description" id="Description" cols="20"></textarea>

        <br>

        <input type="button" value="Save" id="btnSaveDocument">
        <input type="button" value="Close" id="btnClose">
    </div>
</form>
```

Example 5:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
```

---

Just to save on time, here is what I have tried:

1. Adding requestValidationMode="2.0" to the web.config.
2. Adding HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true; to the view.
3. Adding HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true; to the view.
4. Getting the most recent version of jquery and the validate plugin. When it comes to jquery, the most recent is 1.* series, since we have to support ie8 and can't use 2.*.
5. Checking if the FormContext is null and creating a new one if it is.
6. Checking if the scripts are being loaded. The answer is yes.
7. Including unobtrusive.ajax. Doesn't help.
8. Setting ClientValidationEnabled to true and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled to true.

A final note: this is on a Server 2012 machine running IIS 8. This is not a partial view.

Hopefully one of you have run into this. Everywhere I look online says to do one of those 7 options, and none have helped.

Edit:
After looking into things for quite a bit more (couple days since original posting) I have found that the window.mvcClientValidationMetadata property is being set to the correct rullings in the javascript, but the hookups are missing, so when validation is run, the fields aren't actually validated.

Comment: No ideas? This issue is causing many of our tests to fail because none of the client validation is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that I accidentally fixed it. I made a change to the web config that made it invalid, pushed it to production, and then got the good ol' errors associated with that. So I fixed the problem, and pushed up what used to be there and suddenly everything worked.

From what I can tell is that somehow IIS was reading a different web config or something in some sort of hidden cache, and it wasn't until there was an invalid one that it cleared it out. Strange, but at least now it is fixed.

As a side note, I had added a second modulesnode on accident that caused the web.config error in an attempt to set runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to true, but that was already there. If anyone else runs into a similar issue, I hope that causing a web.config error and then fixing it fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just providing some leads.

Setting ClientValidationEnabled to true should result in a span tag being created even if you didn't include JQuery and set UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled to true

Here is the method for creating the span:

```
    private static MvcHtmlString ValidationMessageHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata modelMetadata, string expression, string validationMessage, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        string fullHtmlFieldName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(expression);
        FormContext clientValidation = htmlHelper.ViewContext.GetFormContextForClientValidation();
        if (!htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey(fullHtmlFieldName) && clientValidation == null)
            return (MvcHtmlString)null;

        ModelState modelState = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState[fullHtmlFieldName];
        ModelErrorCollection modelErrorCollection = modelState == null ? (ModelErrorCollection)null : modelState.Errors;
        ModelError error = modelErrorCollection == null || modelErrorCollection.Count == 0 ? (ModelError)null : Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<ModelError>((IEnumerable<ModelError>)modelErrorCollection, (Func<ModelError, bool>)(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.ErrorMessage))) ?? modelErrorCollection[0];
        if (error == null && clientValidation == null)
            return (MvcHtmlString)null;

        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("span");
        ...
        return TagBuilderExtensions.ToMvcHtmlString(tagBuilder, TagRenderMode.Normal);
    }
```

Maybe you are accessing a cached output? Check that:

1. Sserver isn't returning a cached version
2. If you using [HTML5 application cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache), clear it or update the manifest.

Comment: I have gotten the spans to show up before using Html.EnableClientValidation() in the view, but because none of the validation is being detected, it just creates a span with the following html: <span style="font-size:16pt;" id="Name_validationMessage" class="field-validation-valid">*</span>

Comment: As another note, I turned off caching. That didn't fix a thing.

Comment: That is the span format if UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled is false... I run out of ideas already